# Unable to query PG database using koa-pg middleware on Koa on localhost

Tags: postgresql, koa

In the past I've been able to connect to a postgres db using `koa-pg` middleware connected to a database hosted on Heroku, but I'm having problems connecting to a locally-hosted database.

Specifically, the error I have is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`.

The following is my setup on the single-file app:

```
const koa = require('koa');
let route = require('koa-route'); // For calling specific routes
let request = require('koa-request');  // For RESTful requests
let paramify = require('koa-params'); 
var koaPg = require('koa-pg');
let pg = require('pg'); // .native;
let cors = require('koa-cors');
let parser = require('xml2js').parseString;

// pg.defaults.ssl = true;

route = paramify(route);
let param = route.param;
let get = route.get;

let app = koa();
let appPort = (process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.use(cors());
app.use(koaPg('postgres://localhost:5432/ttc_clustering_dev'));
```

And the following is the route where the issue lies:

```
app.use(route.get('/initialDefaultRouteQuery', function *() {
  let options = {
    url: 'http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=vehicleLocations&a=ttc&r=60'
  }
  let xmlResponse = yield request(options)
  let jsResponse = ''
  parser(xmlResponse.body, function(err,result){
    //Extract the value from the data element
    jsResponse = result
    if (err !== null) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    } else {
      console.log('Success in parsing from XML to JSON')
    }
  });

  let i = 0
  while (i < jsResponse.body.vehicle.length) {
    let query_content = `INSERT INTO temp_records (route_id, bus_id, capture_time, geometry) VALUES ('60', '${jsResponse.body.vehicle[i].$.id}', ${Date.now() - (jsResponse.body.vehicle[i].$.secsSinceReport * 1000)}, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${jsResponse.body.vehicle[i].$.lng} ${jsResponse.body.vehicle[i].$.lat})'))` 

    let result = yield pg.db.client.query_(query_content)
    console.log('result:' + result)
    i += 1;
  }
  this.body = 'Finished!'
}));
```

It appears I've used the proper setup according to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-pg), but there's likely something I'm missing here. Does anyone else see where I'm falling flat?

The full file can be found here: https://github.com/brianbancroft/ttc-clustering/blob/add-records-to-db/server/app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the docs it should be:

```
let result = yield this.pg.db.client.query_(query_content)
```

instead of

```
let result = yield pg.db.client.query_(query_content)
```

So the `this.` is missing.

And reviewing your code, you are explicitly requiring `pg`, so your code is calling that one instead the one from `koa-pg`. Therefore pg.db seems not to be defined. Makes sense?